Violated assumption of independence in logistic regression
In order to predict forest fires occurrence, some studies (study 1,study 2)used meteorological data plus vegetation and topographical data. I'm trying to do the same for a different location but I'm thinking that meteorological variables like temp and precipitation values are dependent both spatially and Temporally but looking at the lit, they don't mention this problem and they just conduct a multicollinearity test. Additionally, a fire in location x can be induced by a nearby fire in location y so the assumption of observations being independent is false am i right ?
What am i getting wrong about independence of observations concerning logistic regression and what can be an alternative model for such problem?


but I'm thinking that meteorological variables like temp and precipitation values are dependent both spatially and Temporally ...

Yes, they are probably dependent, but you are using them as predictors in some regression model, so are conditioning on them. In conditional (regression) models the probability distribution of regressor variables do not play a role, since you are conditioning on their observed values.

Additionally, a fire in location x can be induced by a nearby fire in location y so the assumption of observations being independent is false am i right ?

Yes, this is correct. You might need to model spatial or temporal dependence.

Thanks for taking the time to answer.So if they are dependent, doesn't that mean the assumption is violated? could you please elaborate on how the assumption still holds in such case?

would be clarify your answer more, thank you @kjetil
